# Do I need to sanitize strings used to declare geometric shapes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want an SQL function to receive a string such as `point_str = "47.572820 -34.628906"`. Inside the function, the string will be converted into a shape variable, for example by `SET xpoint = PointFromText( concat("POINT(", point_str, ")") );`

Before sending this string from php to sql, do I need to sanitize it (for example with `floatval`)?

Comment: If the point is something that the user is entering, then yes. You need to sanitize it. If you are not just being safe and sanitizing everything, then the only question should be "is this data in **any way** at **any time** influenced by the user". Even if they are clicking a point on a map and you are sending a direct export from the map. The user created that point, check it. Even if you have the data already and they are clicking a button to add 1 to a number, check it. Even if you are querying a value out of the db just to insert it elsewhere. If the user added the initial value, check it.

Comment: The shapes' data will be entered by an user, but it will not be stored in a database. Would it not be secure, then, to just convey it to the DB by using bindValue and be done with it (not using floatval or anything like that in php)?

Comment: It is possible that the data sent to the server isn't even a number. You need to verify that at the very least. I can make a form on any site that posts to your server with whatever values I want. I could just go and change your javascript values before they are sent to the server. I could make the browser submit a fake ajax request with whatever I want. Point is, this is VERY easy to do. So, like I said above, "is the data in **any way** at **any time** influenced by the user"?

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error on both situations; either when the text is entered, of when it is read. When the data is read and the function fails to genereate a shape, all visitors of that page will see the error.

If you throw the error on creation, there is only one person who gets an error plus the wrong data will never be in your database. So yes. If the output is dependent on the input make sure the input is suitable for the output and sanitize it.